# How to execute seperate .msi in post build event

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2015, installation, post-build-event

I am using Visual Studio Installer setup project to install my program, in Visual Studio Community 2015. My program, however, is reliant on SqlLocalDB. I have the SqlLocalDB.msi and I would like to install it after my program installs. So, I package it in my installer, into the folder that my program goes as well. Then, in the post build events I have

```
msiexec /a "c:\Program Files(x86)\TowerSearch\SqlLocalDB.msi"
```

That is the directory that the installer installs to. However, this fails with error code 1619 with unspecified error when I try to build the project. I also tried some other variations, but to no avail. I'm probably doing something silly that makes it not work, but I don't know what. So, how would you install a separate .msi file, if it's even possible?

Comment: I've also tried this in admin cmd with the directory that I have the .msi, minus the quotes, and it executed properly

Comment: Do you really want `/a` instead of `/i`? That tells msiexec to do an administrative install, which extracts the file contents of the .msi (skipping registry, etc.) rather than installing the .msi.

Comment: If the .msi can install can install with /i then I'll use /i, but I still have the problem where it gives me the build error

Comment: Double check what actually happens by creating a log (add `/l*v <path\to>\msi.log`) and figure out what went wrong. If you're not running Visual Studio elevated, the context difference may be the blocker, though perhaps you could leverage [`MSIINSTALLPERUSER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007.aspx) on its command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to expand on what your goal is here.

If you are on your dev system then postbuild events are called by the Visual Studio build process. However you cannot install the same MSI twice, so it's not clear what you are trying to do. You have that SQL on your dev system already, so you cannot install it again. Error 1619 means it cannot find the file.

If this is intended for client systems (not your development system) then postbuild events don't apply - they are a development thing, not a deployment method. The way you install a prerequisite like SQL is to have it in the Prerequisites of your setup program, where it generates a setup.exe that installs those prerequisites and then installs your MSI file.

Comment: Ah, so I want a Prerequisite, not a post build. Thank you, that's what I needed!